# An example of a strongly convex function whose gradient is Lipschitz and satisfies $0< \mu < L<1$

Tags: convex-optimization

Can someone please help me give like two examples of a strongly convex function whose gradient is Lipschitz  with constant $L$ whose strong convexity parameter is denoted by $\mu$ and satisfies the following condition:
$0<\mu <L<1$.

An example I could think of is $0.5x^2$ but in this case the Lipschitz and strong convexity parameter are not less than one.

Comment: Which other examples have you tried? What exactly are the respective values for $\mu$, $L$?

Comment: Try $f(x,y) = {1 \over 2} (\alpha x^2 + \beta y^2)$, compute $L$, $\mu$ in terms of $\alpha,\beta$.